# Bad configuration option: ServerAliveInterval

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, openssh

I have just got a new server and was trying to make sure the `ServerAliveInterval` was long enough so I didn't keep getting thrown out.

```
root@server:~# sudo sshd -T
/etc/ssh/sshd_config: line 31: Bad configuration option: ServerAliveInterval
/etc/ssh/sshd_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
root@server:~# ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.7, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

Why do I still get this error even though I'm up to do and have OpenSSH

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Server option is called `ClientAliveInterval` as per manual page for `sshd_config`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's an existing bug for WSL

Workaround with below command

```
sudo sed -i 's/ServerAliveInterval/ClientAliveInterval/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/server_alive.conf
sudo service ssh restart
 * Restarting OpenBSD Secure Shell server sshd                                                              [ OK ]
```